# Installing NLTK on MACOS

Tags: python, macos, machine-learning, deep-learning, nltk

I am trying to install NLTK on my 2015 Mac Pro with Mac OS Mojave.

I used

```
sudo pip install nltk
```

It downloaded the setup file and installed successfully.

When I go into python and type

```
nltk.download()
```

I get this

```
NLTK Downloader
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q) Quit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloader>
```

After using 'd', it downloaded a few packages and modules.

But, I cannot use nltk when I try to run this

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
data = "All work and no play makes jack dull boy. All work and no play makes jack a dull boy."
print(sent_tokenize(data))
```

This gives me an error saying:

```
File "token.py", line 1, in <module>
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
from nltk.collocations import *
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 38, in <module>
from nltk.util import ngrams
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/util.py", line 10, in <module>
import inspect
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
import tokenize
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tokenize.py", line 31, in <module>
from token import *
File "/Users/Documents/NLTK/token.py", line 1, in <module>
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
from nltk.tokenize.mwe import MWETokenizer
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/mwe.py", line 31, in <module>
from nltk.util import Trie
ImportError: cannot import name Trie
```

Please help!

Comment: Hello. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to `python` console and type

```
nltk.download('all')
```